# How to add event listener with same class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two `li` with `class="tree"` in a `ul`, I want to set a `height"` to `ul.sub-menu` when someone clicks on its parent `li`. But It not working for the second `li`. **Run snippet**

```js
document.querySelector(".tree").addEventListener("click",  function () {
    var height = document.querySelector(".sub-menu").scrollHeight;   
    document.querySelector(".sub-menu").style.height = height + "px";
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
    position: relative;
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.3s;
        
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="tree">
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tree">
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you can use different id for items.

Comment: You should probably use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead of `document.querySelector()`.

Answer (score 5):

querySelector will return only the first element.

However it is recommended to delegate from the closest common static container - this is also much more elegant than looping over all elements to add eventListeners to each

```js
document.getElementById("topUl").addEventListener("click",  function (e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("li");
  if (tgt.classList.contains("tree")) {
    const sm = tgt.querySelector(".sub-menu");
    const height = sm.scrollHeight;   
    sm.style.height = height + "px";
  }  
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
    position: relative;
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.3s;
        
}
```

```html
<ul id="topUl">
    <li class="tree">
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tree">
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use querySelectorAll to select all the classes, and add eventListener inside loop

```
   document.querySelectorAll(".tree").forEach(i => i.addEventListener(
        "click",/*your code here*/));
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `forEach()` method.

```js
let tree = document.querySelectorAll(".tree");
let height = document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu");

tree.forEach(function(tree_current, index) {
  tree_current.addEventListener("click",  function () {      
    height[index].style.height = height[index].scrollHeight + "px";
  });   
})
```

```css
.sub-menu {
    position: relative;
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.3s;
        
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="tree">
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="tree">
        <a href="#">Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah, yeah. it is `this.querySelector(".subMenu")` anyway clunky to index your way into this

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector()` returns the **first** object matching the query, not all of them. You can check them by pasting `console.log(document.querySelector('.tree'));` at the top of your JS file, and you'll see that it only logs your first element. If you want to add the listener to all of your elements matching the query, you need to use `document.querySelectorAll()` and iterate over that array using `forEach`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tree').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    /* Code Here */
}));
```

Another issue you'll face with your code is that your other query selector also returns the first occurrence of `.sub-menu`. To fix it, you can change

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tree').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    /* Code Here */
}));
```

to

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tree').forEach(el => {
    const submenu = el.querySelector('.sub-menu');
    el.addEventListener('click', () => submenu.style.height = submenu.scrollHeight + "px");
});
```

Since `.sub-menu` is a child of `.tree` in your hierarchy, this will only search your `.tree` for instances of `.sub-menu` and hence return the correct element you need. Your final code would then look like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tree').forEach(el => {
  const submenu = el.querySelector('.sub-menu');
  el.addEventListener('click', () => submenu.style.height = submenu.scrollHeight + "px");
})
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="tree">
    <a href="#">Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="tree">
    <a href="#">Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub Item2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Don't repeat yourself. To avoid having to lookup the element every time the button is clicked we cache it as soon as we initialise the listener and the refer to that stored variable in the click handler.

Comment: DRY, please. Cache the element.

Comment: @mplungjan wanted to keep as close to OP's original code as possible, just fixing it. You're right that it's better to encourage DRY, so I edited my answer to reflect it. Thanks :)

Comment: Because I can't see it changing at runtime. Of course if it does change then it should be inside. That depends on OP's use of these lists

Answer (score 1):

Just use querySelectorAll it is gonna select all classes, and add click event inside it.

```
   document.querySelectorAll(".tree").forEach(

       index => index.addEventListener("click",
        /*your code here*/

   ));
```